# (Fiddle Link Available) ClickHouse changing column timezone by using a separate timezone column(string)

Tags: datetime, clickhouse, metabase

Fiddle Link -> https://fiddle.clickhouse.com/6a18d469-7019-44d2-a65b-828f5c6be755

Example Clickhouse Schema

enter code here

**DateTable**

| Date | Timezone |
| --- | --- |
| May 19, 2023, 04:00:00 | Europe/London |
| May 19, 2023, 04:00:00 | Asia/Kolkata |

I can change timezone using the function `toTimezone(date, 'Europe/London')`.

But I can't use `toTimezone(date, timezone)`.

I want to run a query like this

```
select toTimezone(date, timezone) from DateTable
```

It says ClickHouse timezone conversion needs a const String. Any workaround over this would help a lot.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Only to hardcode all timezones.

```sql
CREATE TABLE DateTimeTest (`date` DateTime64(3, 'Asia/Kolkata'), timezone String) ENGINE=Memory;

INSERT INTO DateTimeTest VALUES ('2019-01-01 04:00:00', 'Asia/Kolkata');
INSERT INTO DateTimeTest VALUES ('2019-01-01 04:00:00', 'America/New_York');
INSERT INTO DateTimeTest VALUES ('2019-01-01 04:00:00', 'Asia/Kolkata');


SELECT
   multiIf(
     timezone='Asia/Kolkata',toString(date, 'Asia/Kolkata'),
     timezone='America/New_York',toString(date, 'America/New_York'),
     toString(date, 'UTC')
  ) r
FROM DateTimeTest;

┌─r───────────────────────┐
│ 2018-12-31 17:30:00.000 │
│ 2019-01-01 04:00:00.000 │
│ 2019-01-01 04:00:00.000 │
└─────────────────────────┘
```