# Clickhouse toTimeZone only accept argument is a constant

Tags: timezone, clickhouse

Has anyone faced an issue while using Clickhouse query with [totimezone](https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/functions/date-time-functions#totimezone)?
Since it only accept argument as a constant.
Similar question on [github](https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/issues/33382).
Any thought or finding is much appreciated.

I tried creating custom function and this approach did not work as well

Comment: there is no good solution. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76286180/